# Replacing Specific Lines in a File with Lines in a Different File in Python

Tags: python, file, file-writing

I have a f1.txt and f2.po file and I want to replace certain lines (that contains the string "msgstr") in this f2.po file with lines in the f1.txt file.

I mean, the first line that contains the string "msgstr" should replace with the first line in the .txt file and the second line that contains the string "msgstr" should replace with the second line in the .txt file.
I hope I've been able to explain it completely.

I know how to overwrite a file but I can't figure out how to overwrite only certain lines. I'de be very appreciated if you could help.

Comment: Generally it's much easier to create a NEW file that has the lines you want and then rename that file to the old filename, instead of actually editing the old file.

Comment: What if `"msgstr"` appears in three different lines in `f2.po` and `f1.txt` holds only two lines ?

Comment: @Timeless it's impossible because I took the msgstr strings from another .po file which has the same format as f2.po file and then created f1.txt file. Now I just have the replace this strings.

Comment: @JohnGordon how can I do that?

Comment: Open the existing file for reading and the new file for writing.  Read each line in the existing file.  If you want to keep that line, write it to the new file, otherwise skip it.  Rename the file at the end.  What is the difficulty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can walk through the file `f2.po` and whenever a line contains `"msgstr"`, call [`readline`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readline) to ask for the corresponding line in `f1.txt` and if not, keep the original one.

```
import fileinput

with (
    open("f1.txt", "r") as f1,
    fileinput.input(files=("f2.po"), inplace=True) as f2
):
    for line in f2:
        if "msgstr" in line:
            print(f1.readline(), end="")
        else:
            print(line, end="")
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to modify `f2.po` inplace, add a third [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) :

```
with (
    open("f1.txt", "r") as f1,
    open("f2.po", "r") as f2,
    open("f3.po", "w") as f3
):
    for line in f2:
        if "msgstr" in line:
            f3.write(f1.readline())
        else:
            f3.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out myself, I also leave my solution here for those who have the same problem. Also thanks to @Timeless for his answer, it is a much more organized code than mine.

```
f1 = open("directory path\\f1.txt", "r") 
f2 = open("directory path\\f2.po", "r")

#transferring file lines to lists
listOfAllTxtLines = f1.readlines()
listOfAllPoLines = f2.readlines()

f1.close()
f2.close()

#Replacing lines which contains "msgstr" in f2.po with lines in f1.txt
j = 0
i = 0
for line in listOfAllPoLines:
    if "msgstr" in line:
        listOfAllPoLines[i] = listOfAllTxtLines[j]
        j += 1
    i += 1

#creating a new .po file
f3 = open("directory path\\f2_NEW.po", "w")
f3.close()

f4 = open("directory path\\f2_NEW.po", "a")

#writing new lines to the new .po file
for line in listOfAllPoLines:
    f4.write(line)

f4.close()
```